# Testing intersections in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

In the following list `{{1,3,5},{2,4,5},{3,4},{1,5}}`, two elements have an empty intersection. This is not the case of the list `{{1,4,5},{3,4,5},{3,4},{1,3}}`. Is there a simple way to perform such a test? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Great proposals. A priori, speed is not a consideration as far as it applies to lists of up to 6 elements (subsets), even if, in one case, the test has to be done about 60 millions of times... So it may matter and I am amazed by the differences in computation times between the different proposals.

Answer (score 2):

One could compute all the intersections using `DistanceMatrix`, and test for the presence of an empty list

```
hasEmptyIntersectionQ[list_] := MemberQ[DistanceMatrix[list, 
   DistanceFunction -> Intersection], {}, {2}] 

hasEmptyIntersectionQ@{{1, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 3}}
(* False *)

hasEmptyIntersectionQ@{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}}
(* True *)
```

Comment: Also possible: `MemberQ[DistanceMatrix[list, DistanceFunction -> IntersectingQ], 
 Abs[False], {2}]`. ;)   In general, checking for intersection should be faster than computing the intersection.

Comment: I was just noticing `IntersectingQ` in your post.  I wish `DistanceMatrix` wasn't so stupid as to wrap the `False` with `Abs`.

Comment: If `IntersectingQ` were implemented in the kernel it would indeed be faster, but it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that `DistanceMatrix` has some considerable overhead. `Outer` with `IntersectingQ` is an order of magnitude faster for this example. But fo longer input lists, `DistanceMatrix` with `Intersection` seems to be faster. I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[list_List] := Not[And @@ Flatten[Outer[IntersectingQ, #, #, 1] &[list]]]

f[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}}]
f[{{1, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 3}}]
```

> True
>
> False

## Edit

Because I like `SparseArray`s a lot, here a variant involving `SparseArray` that solves this problem for lists of *positive integers* quite quickly:

```
h[list_List] := Module[{A},
  A = SparseArray[
    Join @@ MapIndexed[{x, i} \[Function] Thread[{x, i[[1]]}], list] -> 1
    ];
  (A\[Transpose].A)["Density"] < 1.
  ]
```

A timing comparison:

```
a = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]], {i, 1, 1000}];
r1 = f[a]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r2 = hasEmptyIntersectionQ[a]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r3 = h[a]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 == r2 == r3
```

> 6.89991
>
> 2.73299
>
> 0.015683
>
> True

Answer (score 1):

Two additional ways, the first short and slow, the second ugly but fast:

```
ClearAll[hasDisjointPairQa, hasDisjointPairQb]
hasDisjointPairQa = Or @@ DisjointQ @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] &;


hasDisjointPairQb = Module[{a = False}, 
  Do[If[DisjointQ[#[[i]], #[[j]]], a = True; Break[]], 
  {i, Length[#] - 1}, {j, i + 1, Length@#}]; a] &;

lists1 = {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}};
lists2 = {{1, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 3}};
hasDisjointPairQ /@ {lists1, lists2}
```

> {True, False}

```
hasDisjointPairQb /@ {lists1, lists2}
```

> {True, False}

Timings using Henrik's setup (`f` and `h` are from Henrik's answer and `hasEmptyIntersectionQ` from Jason B.'s):

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]], {i, 1, 1000}];

f[a] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.23578, True}

```
hasDisjointPairQa[a] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.10347, True}

```
hasEmptyIntersectionQ[a] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.08455, True}

```
h[a] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0256391, True}

```
hasDisjointPairQb[a] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000284839, True}

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I'm not quite clear about your question.
If you want the testing function to return True only when any two elements of the list have nonempty intersection, Jason B. and Henrik Schumacher gave the correct answers. If you want the testing function to return True as far as there are two elements of the list have nonempty intersection, the following function would work:

```
f[x_]:=DuplicateFreeQ[x//Flatten]
```

Comment: I wanted to have a testing function returning True whenever two elements (subsets) in the list have an empty intersection. I have so far used hasEmptyIntersection (by Jason) and h (by Henrik), the latter being definitely faster.